# JButton pressed doesn't work with JTextField

Tags: jbutton

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.FlowLayout;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;

import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JTextField;

public class guiDemo extends JFrame {

public static void main(String[] args) {

    JFrame myGUI = new guiDemo();
    myGUI.setSize(750, 600);
    myGUI.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    myGUI.setVisible(true);

    JButton myButton = new JButton("Click Me");
    myButton.setSize(300, 150);
    myGUI.add(textField);
    myGUI.add(myButton);
    myGUI.setLayout(new FlowLayout());

    JTextField textField = new JTextField("Hello GUI World!");



    myButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

            String textInField = textField.getText();
            textField.setForeground(Color.BLUE);
            System.out.println(textInField);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

All I am trying to do is when the button is pressed show the text in JTextField above the button. At the same time the text must be blue. I Don't exactly know how to get the text above the button. I think it has to do with JPanel but not positive. The oracle tutorials to me are not easily understandable to me.

The output is printing the text I want in the console not my container I created.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`JTextField textField = new JTextField("Hello GUI World!");` must declare before using it `myGUI.add(textField);`

EDIT:
After checking your code, you should put `myGUI.setVisible(true);` at the end of `main` function. For me, it works like this.[image]

Comment: So I placed myGUI.add(textField); after JTextField textField = new JTextField("Hello GUI World!"); and it still only prints "Hello GUI World!" in the console and not in a textbox above the button.

Comment: I Placd it at the bottom which is fine but the text box should pop up until I click on the button not before. Where is my issue there?